# mutt: tag-prefix not working for macros?

Tags: mutt

Every message I delete I also want to mark as read. Thus I redefine the key binding `d` as follows

```
macro index d ":set resolve=no<enter><clear-flag>N:set resolve=yes<enter><delete-message>"
```

Deleting messages, regardless if they are read or unread, deletes them and, well, also clears flag `N`. Everything fine here.

However, if I want to delete multiple mails by marking and deleting them, nothing happens. That means, I tag same mails via `t` and then I proceed with `;d` and nothing happens. Does this mean that tag-prefixing does not work for macros? Any ideas?

I'm using mutt version 1.12.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<tag-prefix>` repeats the next *instruction*, not the next *keystroke*. When a keystroke is a binding, it's by definition only one instruction, and you get what you expect. When a keystroke is a macro, it triggers only the first instruction in the macro.

See https://gitlab.com/muttmua/mutt/wikis/MuttGuide/Macros#special-usage-applying-to-several-tagged-entries for some suggestions on this use case.

Comment: Uhh haven't expect that. Is it possible to have mutt emit a warning in such cases? I mean if I configure a macro with more than one instruction and use it in a case where exactly one instruction is executed, getting a warning would be user friendly. Nonetheless, thanks for your advice!

Comment: If I remember, there's no alternative except with third-party patches.